# What is the best way to neatly write HTML Mark-up inside PHP

Tags: php, html

Before you close this question, I know that this is a subjective matter. What one person thinks is the best way, will not be the opinion of another. However, I am open to try anything that I need necessary and as the writer of this question should be the judge of the answers.

---

I am developing a rather complicated website which relies on several queries to the database to pull certain information. I loop through datasets and begin constructing HTML Mark-up.

This is just a general question, so there is no need to include the specifics. In general the format of my PHP for the site (excuding most of the structural HTML) is as follows:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT SOMETHING");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $class = "";
    // do some more queries based on these rows

    if ($error) {
        $class = "error";
    } else { // note, I realize 
        $class = "success";
    }

    echo "<div class='something'>"
    if ($conditionTrue) {
        echo "<div class='$class'>More information..</div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

The following example looks fine, but this quickly becomes messy as more markup is added. I am not looking for a templating engine, and not necessarily a library, but just general practices that other PHP developers do to keep code like this more manageable. Please also note, that separating the data into Logic and Layout is an option but I am seeking for more.

Comment: Look up the MVC concept, invest in learning a framework such as `Laravel`, use a templating engines such as `blade`, etc etc. There's *tons* of resources available to you; but unfortunately, Stackoverflow isn't the best place to ask where to find them.

Comment: What more are you looking for besides separating logic and layout. From what I see, that is the only thing you need.

Comment: You should never mix mix your logic/queries with the output like that. MVC is a lie, but what you *should* do is [separate the concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: What would be the `$error` in your example code? A database error or something in the row.

Comment: @Andrew $error would be an evaluation of a specific row. For example, `$error = $row['approved'] != 1`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 3):

Sure, writing HTML inside PHP will get other PHP and HTML dev's heated everytime. Personally, I don't think there is any problem with it. This is how I would do it:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT SOMETHING");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
$class = "";
// do some more queries based on these rows

if ($error) {
    $class = "error";
} else { // note, I realize 
    $class = "success";
}

?>

<div class='something'>

<?php 

if ($conditionTrue) { ?>

<div class='$class'>More information..</div>

<?php } ?>

</div> 

<?php } ?>
```

This is the basic idea, indenting in SO is a pain. You can close the php tag, write HTML and open it again to close your statement.

**EDIT**! I should add that if you try to put headers in PHP AFTER you write some HTML, it will give you an error. Specifically, headers already sent. If you want to redirect the page using headers, it needs to be BEFORE ANY HTML!

Comment: But you _will_ need an echo here, `<div class='$class'>More information..</div>` - otherwise it will just output `$class` as the _literal_ content of the class attribute.

Comment: And FYI, when using this method of separating PHP and HTML, many people prefer the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) - it usually reads easier than having stuff like this `<?php } ?>` appear all the time. (But that is more or less a matter of taste/personal preference, yes.)

Comment: What is your opinion on intentions?